# Swollen right leg on tortoise

Tags: health, reptiles, tortoises

I just discovered that my tortoise's right front leg is swollen. I don't see any redness, and no problems with movement except for its right leg, which it can't extend.

It eats well. Its diet consists of vegetables, mostly fruits (like berries, banana, etc.; it doesn't eat fruit that is a bit sour) and sometimes plain bread and whole grain cereal.

I'm not sure what type of tortoise it is but it's just a regular one. I've had it for about 10 years already, if I'm not mistaken. I keep it indoors in a large tank. This is the first time that something like this has happened to my tortoise.

Comment: Can you post a picture? Maybe an extra set of eyes could spot something. It could also help with letting you know what kind of tortoise it is.

Comment: Also, probably irrelevant in this case, but what is the temperature and humidity in the terrarium?

Comment: We need to know the species too, another reason for a picture.